# Как расставить запятые?

Tags: запятая

Поэтому перед тем как сделать это, несколько раз проверьте...

Answer (score 6):

Да, внутри союза перед тем как запятая не нужна. Но перед ним я бы поставила, отнеся наречие поэтому к главной части. *Поэтому несколько раз проверьте, перед тем как сделать это. Поэтому, перед тем как сделать это, несколько раз проверьте.*

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, имеющейся запятой достаточно, так как здесь используется союз "перед тем как"